# Integer incompatible Joda and Java lang

Tags: java, treemap

Getting this error:

```
 incompatible types
    required: java.lang.Integer
    found: java.util.Map.Entry<org.joda.time.DateTime.java.lang.Integer>
```

and the code resulting in error:

```
public static void checkRange() {

        DateTime startx = new DateTime(startDate.getTime());
        DateTime endx = new DateTime(endDate.getTime());

        //produces submap
        Map<DateTime, Integer> nav = map.subMap(startx, endx);

        //this is the line causing the error:
        for (Integer capacity : map.subMap(startx, endx).entrySet()) {

        }
}
}
```

I have startDate and endDate defined as Date earlier then I convert them here as u can see to DateTime. I dont think that's the problem
and the map is

```
public static TreeMap<DateTime, Integer> map = new TreeMap<DateTime, Integer>();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `entrySet()` returns the "rows" of the map, that is, the `Entry` objects containing both they keys and the values. To iterate over just the values, you can use `map.values()`, which is a collection of `Integer` in this case.

Comment: brilliant :D error gone Thanks a lot...and good explanation that I didn't clearly know

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you want is `map.subMap(startx, endx).values()` instead of `map.subMap(startx, endx).entrySet()`.